# implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'void *' is disallowed with ARC

Tags: objective-c, core-audio, automatic-ref-counting

What does this mean and what alternative do I have?

> implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'void *' is disallowed with ARC

I am porting an Xcode3 project to iOS5 which uses AudioSessionInitialize like this

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, self);
```

where `self` here is a ViewController.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can't do implicit casts to `void*` anymore, `AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, objc_unretainedPointer(self));` should do the trick.

EDIT:
Historical point, the answer above was from before the `__bridge` casts were finalized. In modern code the correct answer is that provided by @KazukiSakamoto, `AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, (__bridge void*)self);`

Answer (score 50):

- [Automatic Reference Counting - 3.2.4. Bridged casts](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects.operands.casts)

You should use __bridge cast for it.

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, (__bridge void *)self);
```

Comment: could you or @Joshua Weinberg comment on whether you need a bridged cast or whether @Joshua Weinberg's answer (`objc_unretainedPointer`) is right? The ARC compiler likes to suggest `__bridge`

Comment: objc_unretainedPointer is "__attribute__((cf_returns_not_retained)) const void *objc_unretainedPointer(id object) {return object;}". These both have the same effect, however, at least, __bridge is well documented and objc_unretainedPointer is undocumented.

Comment: Thanks @Kazuki Sakamoto, it's the second time I'm back at this answer and your comment is really helpful.

Comment: This is the correct answer, I believe I answered before the __bridge casts were added.