# ARC type Casting Xcode 4.2

Tags: casting, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

```
NSString *cell2val= (NSString *) 1;
```

convert an integer value to nsstring show the following error message
Cast to 'NSString *' of a non-Objective-C to an Objective-C pointer is disallowed with Automatic Reference Counting

Comment: See Stack overflow [post][1]. this worked for me.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868130/implicit-conversion-of-an-objective-c-pointer-to-void-is-disallowed-with-arc

Answer (score 0):

You're telling the compiler that 1 is the virtual address of an NSString, which it probably isn't.

I'm guessing you meant to do something like this:

```
NSString *cell2val = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just construct a string based on the integer.

```
NSString *cell2val = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",1];
```

if you were working with NSNumbers you could call stringValue.